# How to use table valued parameter with the IN keyword

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

Edit:

I tried to replace:

```
@LocationIDs NVARCHAR(MAX) = null,
```

with

```
@LocationIDs LocationIdArray READONLY,
```

but now I get an error saying:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationIDs".

--END EDIT--

I have this stored procedure that I need to address:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAP_GetTechnician_Door_Unlock]   
    @LocationIDs NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,  
    @AlarmDateFrom DATETIME = NULL,  
    @AlarmDateTo DATETIME = NULL,  
    @TechnicianID INT = NULL,
    @LocationId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@LocationIDs = 'x')  
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LocationIDs = dbo.fn_GetAll_Location_Id()  
    END

    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @query = 'WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY al.Alarm_Log_ID desc)AS RowNumber,  
 isnull(t.Technician_ID,'''')[Technician_ID], (isnull(t.Last_Name,'''') +'' ''+  isnull(t.Name,''''))  TechnicianName,isnull(t.Emailid,'''') as EmailID,isnull(t.phone,'''') as Phone,dbo.fNAP_DateFormat(al.Alarm_date) as Alarm_date,                  
 Al.Site_ID,s.Name as SiteName,al.point_Address,l.location_Name,l.Location_ID ,shs.StatusData                  
from z_EntityMast_Alarm_Log al                   
left join  z_EntityMast_Technician t on al.Technician_ID=t.Technician_id                  
left join z_EntityMast_Site s on s.Site_ID=al.Site_ID                  
left join z_EntityMast_Location l on s.Location_ID=l.Location_id                  
left join z_EntityMast_Site_Hardware_Status shs on s.site_id=shs.siteid                   
left join z_SysVar_Alarm_Type_00004 at on al.Alarm_Type=at.ID                   
where at.Is_Linkable=1 and al.Alarm_Type !=70'               
if(isnull(@LocationId,0)!=0)            
set @query=@query+' and s.Location_ID ='+convert(varchar(12),@LocationId);            
else            
set @query=@query+' and s.Location_ID in ('+@LocationIDs+')';   
if(isnull(@AlarmDateFrom,0)!=0 and @AlarmDateFrom !='')  
set @query=@query+'and (DATEDIFF(DAY,'''+convert(varchar(30),@AlarmDateFrom)+''', al.Alarm_Date)>=0 and  DATEDIFF(DAY,'''+convert(varchar(30),@AlarmDateTo)+''',al.Alarm_Date)<=0)';                
if(isnull(@TechnicianID,0)!=0)  
set @query=@query+'and t.Technician_ID ='+ convert(varchar(10),@TechnicianID);  
set @query=@query + ')';  
set @query=@query +'select * from CTE ';  

    -- PRINT @query  
    EXEC (@query)  
END
```

I need to optimize it and I have to use table valued parameters for the `LocationIds` parameter, instead of it using `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

The problem is in this line of code:

```
SET @query  = @query + ' and s.Location_ID in ('+@LocationIDs+')';
```

My question is: how does one replace that line of code and replace it with a table valued parameter in such a way that the concatenation would still work?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the result when you print @query from the problematic line you reckon is

Comment: Please see edit. I am now getting the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationIDs"."

Comment: oh i see.. look for dynamic sql with parameter  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: I read that site over and over but I don't know how that would help in this situation..

Comment: When I pasted the SP in and ran it and inspected the SQL I noticed that the last `SELECT * FROM CTE` does not have a space before it. Please inspect your output again. Then copy/paste and run it. The problem is mainly to do with errors in the way you put your dynamic  SQL together.

Comment: Also `s.Location_ID =7and (DATEDIFF(` is missing a space before `and`. Please take the time to inspect the output

Comment: plus this whole chunk at the end - `,al.Alarm_Date)<=0)and t.Technician_ID =6)select * from CTE`

Comment: OK it seems like this question has evolved on to TVP's.

Answer (score 1):

> `SET @query  = @query + ' and s.Location_ID in ('+@LocationIDs+')';`
>   My question is: how does one replace that line of code and replace it
>   with a table valued parameter in such a way that the concatenation
>   would still work?

Suppose your `LocationIdArray` has this definition:

```
create type LocationIdArray as table (LocationId int);
```

Then your `IN` should look like this:

```
and s.Location_ID in (select LocationId from @LocationIDs)
```

This won't work within your `exec` because `@LocationID` is in the outer scope respect to `exec`, you can pass it as a parameter in `sp_executesql` but the best you can do is to rewrite your dynamic query to static one as there is no reason to use dynamic code here.